# Emacs switch to the next window regardless of frame

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'd like for the C-x o command (next window) to include windows in other frames as well as windows in the current frame.

Does anyone know how to pull this off? Is there another command that I should be using? Is there some snippet of elisp magic that can do this with ease?

Answer (score 4):

`C-x o` is `other-window`. To go to an other frame use `C-x 5 o` which is `other-frame`.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to cycle through windows regardless of what frame they're in? That's really what I'm looking for. C-x 5 o looks useful though.

Comment: You can stay in the same window and make the buffers cycle by using `C-x b`. By using `C-x 4 b` the cycling buffers will appear in the "other" buffer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but if you want to just [cycle through buffers in the buffer list](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Select-Buffer.html), regardless of frame:

<kbd>Ctrl x</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl x</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>

These are bound to (next-buffer) and (previous-buffer), respectively.

Comment: Its not what I'm looking for (see corrected question above) but this is still very useful so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This can be a first approximation.
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Cyclic-Window-Ordering.html
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Frames.html

`other-window` has a parameter to control how it deals with frames.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x o")  (lambda ()
                 (interactive)
                 (other-window 1 t)
         (let ((nframe (window-frame (selected-window))))
           (select-frame-set-input-focus nframe)
           (make-frame-visible nframe))))
```

Comment: This is VERY close to what I'm looking for, but the buffers don't cycle, and C-x o doesn't work at all on one of the buffers. Good first approximation though!

Comment: C-x o doesn't work - Does focus jump to another frame? For me it works if I make all frames visible in windows manager.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu, so that might be the issue. For me it goes through the windows in the first frame, correctly jumps to the second frame, and goes through the windows in the second frame, but then stops on the last buffer if finds in the second frame. Doesn't seem to know how to go back to that first buffer in the original frame.

Answer (score 1):

You must press <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>5</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> <kbd>C-h</kbd> to see all functions about working with frames.

Some of these function is other-frame.

Answer (score 1):

I use the version 2.0 of *ace-jump-mode*.  It takes about two minutes to understand how it works and since version 2.0 it allows to "jump" to another frame.  You can jump to any character from any buffer/frame/window that you can actually see on a screen in three or four keypresses.  It's very hard to beat.

It's a gigantic time saver anyway so I'd recommend checking it out because it's really convenient.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AceJump

And the *"Emacs Rocks! Episode 10: Jumping around"* two minutes screencast showing it in action:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZkpmegySnc

Answer (score 1):

From `C-h f next-window`:

> (next-window &optional WINDOW MINIBUF ALL-FRAMES) ...
>
> ALL-FRAMES nil or omitted means consider all windows on WINDOW's
>   frame, plus the minibuffer window if specified by the MINIBUF
>   argument.  If the minibuffer counts, consider all windows on all
>   frames that share that minibuffer too.  The following non-nil values
>   of ALL-FRAMES have special meanings:
>
> - t means consider all windows on all existing frames.
> - `visible' means consider all windows on all visible frames.
> - 0 (the number zero) means consider all windows on all visible and   iconified frames.
> - A frame means consider all windows on that frame only.
>
> Anything else means consider all windows on WINDOW's frame and no
>   others.

Somewhat ironically, `other-window` supports this as well, as it uses `next-window`. Unfortunately, I don't know of a way to pass non-numeric arguments interactively, but a simple function should do the trick:

```
(defun my-other-window (count)
  (interactive "p")
  (other-window count t))
```

Answer (score 0):

You say *"Is there a way to cycle through windows regardless of what frame they're in? That's really what I'm looking for?"*

Yes, there is, with [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles).

What you request is what command `icicle-select-window` does when you use a prefix arg.  If you want that behavior always, you can define your own command that does it without a prefix arg:

```
 (defun my-select-window ()
   "Select window by name.  Windows of all visible frames are candidates."
   (interactive)
   (let ((current-prefix-arg  1)) (icicle-select-window)))
```

You are prompted for the window name.  But if you just want to cycle, without narrowing the candidates by typing part of the name, then just use `C-down` to get the window you want.

(A *window name* is the name of its displayed buffer, but suffixed as
needed by `[NUMBER]`, to make the name unique.  For example, if you have
two windows showing buffer `*Help*`, one of the windows will be called
`*Help*[2]` for use with this command.)